# how to get youtube videos information in android? -kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube, youtube-api

is there any chance to get video information with or without youtube APIs? right now I'm getting the thumbnail of videos using their video_id but I want information like title, description, views, YouTuber profile picture, and YouTuber name. I looked at youtube docs but just simple things like using players for playing videos.
this is the way I get thumbnails.

```
"https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoID}/0.jpg"
```

also, I'm using youtube API for playing videos in my app with this code.

```
val intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(requireActivity(), "AIzaSyChnBzNGITQM2gUc52RnRfG3eDYmYRAhQ8", video_id)
            startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: You can get all the details of the video with the help of youtube snippet API.  Please [Check here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#Sample_Partial_Requests)

Comment: @ShivamJamaiwar i didn't understand it. it seems for example title written before. Can you show me some example to how to do that?

Comment: In the document itself, they have given some examples. what you didn't understand from that 4 examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these API to get video data
**https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=snippet,statistics&fields=items(id,snippet,statistics)**

**Note**: just add your API key in place of YOUR_API_KEY and pass videoId in place of VIDEO_ID.

**API Response**

```
{ 
 "videos": [
  {
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "snippet": { 
    "publishedAt": "2012-06-20T22:45:24.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
    "description": "Antonio Fuentes speaks to us and takes questions on working with Google APIs and OAuth 2.0.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "categoryId": "28"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3057",
    "likeCount": "25",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "17",
    "commentCount": "12"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, @Shivam Jamaiwar, your answer is partially *incorrect*; that's because the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint *does not have any [request parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) named `videoId`*.

Comment: @stvar, I have used this **search API** with the request parameter like this  **(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=API_KEY&maxResults=1&videoId=BG9bm4TCy64)** and I got success response also with all information.

Comment: Again, @Shivam Jamaiwar, this URL of yours does not work (and cannot work, as per the official specification of `Search.list`). To me it returned one entry of a video that has the ID `0U4P86yaYzI` -- not what you expected `BG9bm4TCy64`.

Comment: Hi @stvar, yes you are right man I just checked. This URL is not working properly, it gives us result of other video. Thank you for correcting me. I will edit my answer.

Comment: so your answer is correct but how am i supposed to use that? I have to parse it? also couldnt take channel picture

Comment: Hi @Morteza, now you have a JSON response and you have to parse it for that you have to learn how json data work. you can create model classes for parsing.